# Existing Function at Runtime Stops Working when Data is Updated using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My project updates icons on a map. I have a list of buttons that describe the various icons placed on the map.  When the user clicks a button in the list the corresponding icon opacity stay at 1 and the other icons opacity goes to zero; so now the viewer only see just the single icon that goes with that selected description.  This concept **works great at the initial run-time**.  The problem I’m running into is **when I update the data, the button list function no longer works.**  The function loses focus of the icons.

The reason I update the data is to highlight color regions.  I have a green region (green icons) and a black region (black icons).  The update of data toggle between these 2 regions.  I still need the list of buttons to isolate the icon with its corresponding description.  The reason why I have this feature, I have some icons layered on top of others.  I need to remove the blocking icons to give the user the ability to hover over the specific icon to see additional information.  I’m building this project with d3.js and the custom function with JavaScript.  I appreciate any help anyone can offer/suggest or I will go with a entirely different approach.

My code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#mapData").append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 650")
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%")
features = svg.append("g")
.attr("class","features");


var select = d3.select('#form1')
  .append('select')
var options = select.selectAll('option')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('option')
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return 'option option' + d.id;
  })
  .attr('id', function(d) {
    return 'tankValue' + d.id;
  })
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.discrip;
  })
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return ' tankItem tankItem' + d.id;
  })
  .attr('value', function(d, i) {
    return i;
  });

var button = $(".tankItem");
var gallery = $('.mark');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    button[index].onclick = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
        gallery[i].style.opacity = i === index ? 1 : 0;
      }
    }
  }(i));
}

function updateDay1() {
  d3.selectAll(".mark").remove();

  d3.csv("data/data.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) return alert("error");
    var marks = features.selectAll(".mark")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("image")
      .filter(function(d) {
        if (d.area == "black") {
          return d.graphic
        }
      })
      .attr('class', function(d) {
        return 'stagger mark mark' + d.id;
      })
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return "feature-" + i;
      })
      .attr('width', 35)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d.graphic
      })
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return projection([d.graphicLong, d.graphicLat])[0]
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return projection([d.graphicLong, d.graphicLat])[1]
      })
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("mousedown", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html("<div class='tipClose'><img src='graphic/closeBtn.svg' alt='Close Icon'></div><strong>Equipment Type:</strong> <br><span style    ='color:red'>" + d.discrip + "</span></br><a class='fancybox-thumb fancybox-button iframe fancybox'  rel='fancybox-button'  rel='fancybox-thumb'   data-fancybox-group='" + d.clusterGrp + "'   title='" + d.imageTitle + " '  href='graphic/" + d.popup + "' ><img src='graphic/" + d.popupThumb + "' alt='Image'></a>")
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 300) + "px");
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .append("features:title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      })
  });
}
```

Comment: Did I miss is somewhere? What is `features`

Comment: features is the name of my svg group. I will add that part to the script I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is  HERE you attach the event handlers to items on the page:

```
var button = $(".tankItem");
var gallery = $('.mark');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    button[index].onclick = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
        gallery[i].style.opacity = i === index ? 1 : 0;
      }
    }
  }(i));
}
```

// THEN here you remove those items and thus the event handlers:

```
function updateDay1() {
  d3.selectAll(".mark").remove();
```

Either re-execute that event handler attachment (in a function perhaps) or attach the handler to the container of those elements.

Note this form attaches to a container:

```
$(mycontainerselector).on('click','.tankItem', function(){
```

This might work perhaps:

```
$(mycontainerselector).on('click','.tankItem', function(e){
    var index = $(e.target).index();
    var gallery = $('.mark');
    for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
        gallery[i].style.opacity = i === index ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: I toyed with the a function like you provided - $(mycontainerselector).on('click','.tankItem', function(){ but I could not get it to work with the for loop inside it.  How would you suggest placing the for loop inside the handler you are suggesting? Or how do I rewrite it with your suggested handler.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Mark your solution worked!!!  Thank you so much.  I really really really appreciate your help with this issue!  I will make this as the answer.

Comment: Glad it works! I believe that the important thing here is for you to understand how those event handler attachments work in jQuery, and why a DOM refresh/change impacts them.  Hopefully this gives you  insight into that, if not there are good posts on here in regard to that.

Comment: Thank you for the super advice...will do!